# Is there a measure theoretic version of Stokes's theorem?

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, reference-request, soft-question

Is there a way to generalize Stokes's theorem on manifolds to general measure spaces?

This idea came from trying to generalize the fundamental theorem of calculus to general function/infinite dimensional spaces.

Just wondering if anyone can provide a reference or if this notion would even make sense.

Thanks

Comment: The notion of a differential form uses the algebraic structures on a manifold such as exterior powers of cotangent spaces. On a general measure space, there is not enough structure to talk about such objects, let alone integrate them. So, I don't think it would really make sense.

Comment: If you can find something analogous to a triangulation in an infinite dimensional space. Maybe there's something analogous in Fréchet manifolds...

Comment: So, if a formulation doesn't exist, what extra conditions would need to be imposed on a function space s.t. something analogous would apply?

Comment: I know this question is old but I would like to add a comment. To me the "Stoke's theorem" for measures is just the idea of a $\sigma$-finite product measure and it related theorems as Fubini or Tonelli. Then an interesting idea will be see when, given a measure, we can decompose this measure in some kind of product measure, maybe using what is called in measure theory a "kernel", then we can apply a one-way Fubini theorem.